# Solving a degree-6 Diophantine inequality

Tags: elementary-number-theory, inequality, polynomials, diophantine-equations

While working on a proof, I ended up with the following Diophantine inequality of degree-6:

$$
a_1^6-2a_1^5+a_1^4 (1-4n)+8a_1^3 n+a_1^2 (4n^2+8n)-8a_1 n^2+16n^2 \ge 0 \tag 1
$$

The variable is $a_1$ and $n \in \mathbb{Z}$ is a known constant, $n \gt 0$. We want $a_1 \in \mathbb{Z}$ satisfying the inequality (1).

**Using Descartes rule of signs**

**Positive roots.** Number of sign changes in $f(a_1): (+,-,-,+,+,-,+) \implies 4$ sign changes. So, the number of positive roots is either $4, 2$ or $0$.

**Negative roots.** Number of sign changes in $f(-a_1): (+,+,+,-,+,+,+) \implies 2$ sign changes. So, the number of negative roots of $f$ is either $2$ or $0$.

**Real roots:** Therefore, there are either $6, 4, 2$ or $0$ real roots (positive or negative).

**Numerical roots calculation**

Assuming there are real roots, I can then use a numerical method like *Newton-Raphson* to calculate the roots and determine the search intervals (where the polynomial takes positive values). Once the intervals are found, I can check the integers in these ranges.

**What are the bounds on the sizes of the intervals to be searched?**

**Is the approach right? Is there anything else I can do to find the roots algebraically?**

Comment: Rational root theorem is your best bet.

Comment: From a quick peek of an implicit graph on Desmos, if $n>0$, all integer values of $a$ solve the inequality. Not sure how to *prove* that, however.

Comment: What is the source of the problem, and what is the exact wording of the original problem?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

All integer values of $a_1$ solve the inequality $(1)$.

Seeing $$
a_1^6-2a_1^5+a_1^4 (1-4n)+8a_1^3 n+a_1^2 (4n^2+8n)-8a_1 n^2+16n^2 \ge 0 \tag 1
$$
as a quadratic inequality on $n$, we get
$$\underbrace{4(a_1^2-2a_1+4)}_{\text{positive}}n^2+(-4a_1^4+8a_1^3)n+a_1^6-2a_1^5+a_1^4\ge 0$$
The discriminant of LHS is
$$D=-16(5a_1^2 - 10a_1 + 4)a_1^4$$
So, we see that $D\gt 0\iff a_1=1$.

For $a_1=1$, we get $4n(3n+1)\ge 0$ which is true.

In conclusion, all integer values of $a_1$ solve $(1)$.